# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' in Keras RNN

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using the RNN class to call a customized class inheriting LSTMCell. When I call the class individually, it works. But when I want to use the RNN and call the class within it, I get this weird error.

Here's my code:

```
def call(self, x, state):
        # Concatenate and return the sequence output
        self.rnn = RNN(
            [lstm_cell(units=self.units,num_cams=self.num_cams) \
            for _ in range(self.decoder_units)], return_sequences=True)(x, state)
        return self.rnn
```

I was hoping to pass a previous RNN's output to another RNN with several parallel units.

Comment: seems like `self.units = None`

Comment: Oh, I didn't share the __init__() snippet, but I assure you that units is set to a default non-None value.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is too vague. After hours of debugging, I realized that the input dimensions did not have a time_step dimension. So the overall architecture goes like this:

```
[LSTM] -> (output, hidden_state) -> [stacked_RNN (with 1 time_step)]
```

As the stacked RNN had only one time_step, I was forwarding the LSTM's output with shape `(batch_size, num_units)` directly to it. I had to add the time_step_axis by expanding the dimensions of the output using `tf.expand_dims(output, axis=1)` to get the shape to become `(batch_size, 1, num_units)`. And this got rid of the error.

I hope this saves someone hours of debugging to get around such a vaguely described error.